# Count Days in Months (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, date

I want to know the **number of days of each month** from **1982-01-01 to 2015-12-31**.
I tried some codes from Matlab Help. till now I wrote this code:

```
t1 = datetime(1982,01,01); %start date
t2 = datetime(2015,12,31); %end date
T = t1:t2; %creating a range
```

no idea how to do it. in the end, I want to have one array (1*408)
thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach. See [`ndgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) and [`datenum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html).

```
years = 1982:2015; % desired range of years
[mm, yy] = ndgrid(1:12, years); % all pairs of month, year
result = datenum(yy(:), mm(:)+1, 1) - datenum(yy(:), mm(:), 1); % adding 1 to the month
% works even for December. 'datenum' gives a result where each unit is one day
```

Comment: This is clever. I was unable to get this working using [`duration`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.html) (e.g. `D = duration(t2-t1,'Format','d')` is handy but doesn't help with breaking out month by month). (+1)