# Create a matrix of random dates dependent on another matrix of months

Tags: matlab, matrix

I currently have the variable months where:

```
months = randi(12,5,1);
```

This creates a 5x1 matrix containing random numbers 1-12 which are representative of months (1 = January, 2 = February etc. )

Assuming a month can only have 31, 30 or 28 days in the case of February, how could I create a second 5x1 matrix in which contains a random date in which occurs within it's respective month?

As an example, if the first randomly generated number in the 'months' matrix is 2 (which represents February, with 28 days per month) how could i create a second 5x1 matrix where all 5 random month values 1-12 are assigned a random number based on the amount of days in it's respective month?

I have tried using a for loop inside a for loop to iterate down each random number 1-12 in column 2 and generate a random date based on it's maximum days in such month (31, 30 or 28 for Feb) but it does not seem to work.

Comment: February doesn't always have 28 days. See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58825815/5211833) on how to do this more neat. Ignoring leap years, however, you can generate an array of size 12-by-1 (or 1-by-12), where each element corresponds to the number of days within that month `[31, 28 31, 30 ...]`. Then simply use your integer numbers to index into that array.

Comment: My bad, i updated my question. Assuming February always has 28 days, i'm still not sure how a 5x1 matrix of random dates are able to be created from the other 5x1 of numbers 1-12 indicating months, as previously mentioned

Comment: Please add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in which you tried to solve this problem. Then there a is a basis for discussion.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Aside: I'm choosing to avoid `months` as a variable name because it is the name of an in-built function.</sup>

First it's worth noting you can use `eomday` to get the number of days in a given month. It requires a year (since February can vary), but if you want to always assume Feb has 28 days you can just pick a year where that is true, like 2022.

```
>> maxd = eomday(2022,1:12)
maxd =
    31    28    31    30    31    30    31    31    30    31    30    31
```

You can use this to get the maximum day number for your random months

```
m = randi(12,5,1); % random months
maxd = eomday(2022,m); % maximum day number
```

Then generate random integers between 1 and `maxd` for each random month

```
d = ceil( rand(size(m)) .* maxd );
```

I'm using `ceil` to round up away from 0, together with `rand` to generate integer days instead of `randi` which can't accept the array of max values we need.

So a one-line solution once you have your array of months (`m`) would be

```
d = ceil( rand(size(m)) .* eomday(2022,m) );
```

If you wanted to avoid `eomday` for some reason (performance maybe) then you could define `maxd=eomday(2022,1:12)` and indexing into it using `m` should work in much the same way.