# Is there a convienient way to call a function multiple times without a loop?

Tags: function, matlab, if-statement, matrix, random

I am currently making some code to randomly generate a set of random dates and assigning them to a matrix. I wish to randomly generate N amount of dates (days and months) and display them in a Nx2 matrix. My code is as follows

```
function dates = dategen(N)

    month = randi(12);

    if ismember(month,[1 3 5 7 8 10 12])
        day = randi(31);
        dates = [day, month];
    elseif ismember(month,[4 6 9 11])
        day = randi(30);
        dates = [day, month];
    else
        day = randi(28);
        dates = [day, month];
    end

end
```

For example if I called on the function, as

```
output = dategen(3)
```

I would expect 3 dates in a 2x3 matrix. However, I am unsure how to do this. I believe I need to include N into the function somewhere but I'm not sure where or how.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid a loop? Aside from that, this is pretty much a duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71737514/create-a-matrix-of-random-dates-dependent-on-another-matrix-of-months/71738146#71738146

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [logical indexing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) as follows:

```
function dates = dategen(N)

months = randi(12, 1, N);

days = NaN(size(months)); % preallocate
ind = ismember(months, [1 3 5 7 8 10 12]);
days(ind) = randi(31, 1, sum(ind));
ind = ismember(months, [4 6 9 11]);
days(ind) = randi(30, 1, sum(ind));
ind = ismember(months, 2);
days(ind) = randi(28, 1, sum(ind));

dates = [months; days];

end
```